# Getting actual value from a column in SQL BD table via linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to be able to retrieve the value stored in a column called `ClientEmail` from a `Client` table in a `TEST` DB. Then I needed to be able to use this value to send out an email e.g:

The following Linq query retrieves the details I need:

```
            var clientEmail = (from c in DB.Clients
                                   where c.ClientID == Convert.ToInt32(Session[Constants.SessionKeys.ClientID])
                                   select new { c.ClientEmail }
                              ).FirstOrDefault();

            string clientMailBox = clientEmail.ToString();
```

Now I want to use the value store in the `clientMailBox` string variable in order to send out an email.

However, the result of the query returns both the name of the column and its value in the following format:

```
{ ClientEmail = test.dep.team"@testemail.co.uk }
```

The  actual value from that column is:

```
test.dep.team"@testemail.co.uk
```

I am expecting to get above value,  instead I am getting:

```
{ ClientEmail = test.dep.team"@testemail.co.uk }
```

Is there anything I am missing from my query ?

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use ToString() on your anonymous object, but take the property you need.

```
 string clientMailBox = clientEmail.ClientEmail;
```

In a projection, if you don't specify  a proprety name, it takes the selected property's name.

And `FirstOrDefault` returns an anonymous object with a `ClientEmail` string property, not a string.

Another (I would say better in this case) way would be to just select the string property.

```
var clientEmail = (from c in DB.Clients
                   where c.ClientID == Convert.ToInt32(Session[Constants.SessionKeys.ClientID])
                   select c.ClientEmail)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then, `clientEmail` would be a string (which may be null).

**EDIT**

Once this is clear, you may use Konstantin Ershov' shorter syntax (which assumes at least .net 4.6 for null conditional operator)

Comment: Thanks Raphael (soory if I missed spelled your name) but that did the trick. I will look at using the shorter syntax suggested by Konstantin

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.

```
string clientEmail = DB.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientID == Convert.ToInt32(Session[Constants.SessionKeys.ClientID]))?.ClientEmail;
```

Comment: Thanks Konstantin the the shorter syntax makes it look much simpler